# Decrypt or extract image from the XML response from the biometric device

Tags: node.js, reactjs, xml

I'm using biometric device in my react project. When i send the request to that device to capture the biometric image, it captures and send this response to me. But i want to know how to decrypt ot extract the image from this XML response.

**Edited the data and key due to sensitive information**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PidData>
  <Resp errCode="0" errInfo="Success." fCount="1" fType="0" nmPoints="17" qScore="69" />
  <DeviceInfo dpId="MANTRA.MSIPL" rdsId="MANTRA.WIN.001" rdsVer="1.0.8" mi="MFS100" mc="MIIEGDCCAwCgAwIBAgIEAX14QDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB6jEqMCgGA1UEAxMhPRlRFQ0ggSU5ESUEgUFZUIExURCAzMVUwUwYDVQQzE0xCLTIwMyBTaGFwYXRoIEhleGEgT3Bwb3NpdGUgR3VqYXJhdCBIaWdoIENvdXJ0IFMuRyBIaWdod2F5IEFobWVkYWJhZCAtMzgwMDYwMRIwEAYDVQQJEwlBSE1FREFCQUQxEDAOBgNVBAgTB0dVSkFSQVQxCzAJBgNVBAsTAklUMSUwIwYDVQQKExxNQU5UUkEgU09GVEVDSCBJTkRJQSBQVlQgTFREMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjAeFw0yMzA4MTkxMzUyNDFaFw0yMzA5MDgwNTM1MjVaMIGwMSUwIwYDVQQDExxNYW50cmEgU29mdGVjaCBJbmRpYSBQdnQgTHRkMR4wHAYDVQQLExVCaW9tZXRyaWMgTWFudWZhY3R1cmUxDjAMBgNVBAoTBU1TSVBMMRIwEAYDVQQHEwlBSE1FREFCQUQxEDAOBgNVBAgTB0dVSkFSQVQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMSQwIgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhVzdXBwb3J0QG1hbnRyYXRlYy5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDEC4oZABvp+g1Wz4PWlTbIMlt0TH/Vamt4ILOd53WXpskHCrsEyLlcpJWUpiGFy8QsN7JxpIJjJt53URbg50cHqmu1vnvxj9S9Z9pfK64CiWLnXaoqYtao6eUmNZkOZMexkvEtDae+/vazXGmmFrvwMLiYZubUdqPUpaMQ0t+KYw5XS1gImJlDOy5Zo8tGee0pOCY/nKlPHOVAhrwJey+lMsQhTUNZV7YENm/hRrHF98wkIa4+lpQJP9w/6DU3Nuly9dx0p5Bg9Usx/KXoDDtjspB0iH+ZRpRQvtdITgz7j6OZ1WwOfVViCnTBxVJtcbzlXorHD8J6PMpXRl6VWb1FAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAFQL1pyqu3N6b7HSGO9FZKCjur6GFrH1vlWGyJ9qcn0Czj5JuR8JXK6xmUnIPlAO6HkshGjZPV5e/iAZIh5O4J0GJCzLcjWiCGBGTc0xNtquuzQaC6potDYk8pA8ekZ7tXH9NBLu/gWtjPeXUh6jRI//6TD9AdgztqbDcsTGd7IwBqduSOG3aO5+oAY3+Cn7zfBujR3l57nfuSb49Ptt0PYnZOzp7yHjL9UIWKljrKkkGoW0CLgqn9/+BJTN40Y4xcVfTbhtPCZuXiRafqU7YiPra8UlKCQRSl50GpbsFJW/ya3eVoYEcZlzyZuOVVu87O0YALxutIzs3zklKu3+zEM=" dc="6690dbd7-0434-4ee3-abc7-e72b8723aff3">
    <additional_info>
      <Param name="srno" value="64242" />
      <Param name="sysid" value="6EAFEBF6EECFFF0" />
      <Param name="ts" value="2023-08-24T19:44:36+05:30" />
    </additional_info>
  </DeviceInfo>
  <Skey ci="202529">rTE4BL4oDENp5m13TAgUhyAtjvwPebXEsCQcrpiev5oL7Ue9k3UYh6ctDZTiySAd3QYJKoiUtIn6WUavIdk2g4OSN/wmGWVEqTdF+KL5I936eucR139sbOjcSdf8dQlsTSkr3WDd3flSdObU1l+IVm0qn5GpCBhf0A/ReO6mew3WIS+bjlhnTa3g0uHQd7p8tCWtsPltLaLCW5V6YKk3nY0fdzWY8aJaWr4IuTiTPvaDBuPyXCQTeEsIO9Y996HDfMSyK3lyKM1TbDSGNsUTZDqvwBJeudp6VxDPVj6xNL3kMEdK0po2D9ub7QbnixIWIen2snBHgxw==</Skey>
  <Hmac>wAkwKjlDTrHjyq1QCpbS//EqnzHwMfwAX17nykqLawCp+pArgngnW</Hmac>
  <Data type="X">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</Data>
</PidData>
```

This is response I'm getting. Can I know how to extract or decrypt the image from this ? So that I can match images to check in my next step.

Comment: This is a base64 string. Google for "node base64 decode", then you should find many answers. Or are you asking hot to get just the base64 string from the XML?